Can increasing concentration of reactants make the RDS no longer the slowest step in the mechanism?
The rate determining step is said to determine the overall rate of reaction because it is the slowest step in the mechanism. However, increasing the concentrations of reactants in this step can increase its rate. Is is ever possible that, by increasing concentration of reactants, the rate of the RDS increases to the point that it is no longer the slowest step in the mechanism?

Yes, this happens. Refer to the limiting cases of Michaelis-Menten kinetics as a concrete example, where the rate determining steps are catalytic step or diffusion.

You can temporarily achieve that by lowering of concentration of reactants.

The rate determining step is named such because it is the slowest out of all the other steps in a reaction. By increasing the concentration, you can at most increase the rate of the overall reaction. When you increase the rate of the RDS, you also increase the rate of all other steps in the reaction, so overall it still ends up being the slowest step.
To illustrate numerically:
Say

A-->B (2 minutes)
B-->C (10 minutes)
C-->D (1 minute)
The times here are just for explanation sake.

Here the second step is the rate determining and by increasing the concentration we do indeed increase its rate. However, steps 1 and 3 also become faster and thus overall 2 still remains RDS. Overall when it initially took 10 minutes to complete it might now take 5, but step 2 still is the slowest.

"When you increase the rate of the RDS, you also increase the rate of all other steps in the reaction" - false in general. Possibly true if the RDS is the first step. There may or may not be a relationship between different steps as the rate is determined by both the rate constant and concentrations of various species. If two steps don't share a dependence either directly or indirectly, their rates are decoupled.
